# Is it discouraged to use if in java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider the following problem: I should turn-off all the lamps in a room. The room is contained in a Set rooms. Is it discouraged to use forEach and if? (I read all my lecture notes nowhere did they mention the .forEach(p -> {if... construct.. However I found it the simplest. If it is discouraged how can I solve the problem otherwise? And why is it discouraged?

```
public void turnOffLampsInRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
    lamps.stream()
    .forEach(p -> {if (p.getRoom() != null && rooms.contains(p.getRoom())) {
        p.turnOff();
    }   
    });
}
```

Comment: For the given case: yes. We could two [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate))s before calling `forEach`

Comment: Exactly as @Turing85 points out: this is what `.filter(...)` is for.

Comment: I tried to solve it with filter without success...Can you help me with .filter?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and share your attempt(s).

Comment: Just use a normal loop. Clearer, shorter, and more efficient.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use loops...

Comment: @user16320675 It's needed because some lamps can be unassigned...

Comment: No but rooms.contains(p.getRoom())) will throw NullPointException if p.getRoom() is null..

Comment: Tested it again: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.equals(Object)" because "o" is null"

Comment: Yes Testcases use Set.of()

Comment: What’s the point of creating a new `HashSet` here (`new HashSet<>(lamps)`)? Why don’t you use `lamps.stream()` directly?

Comment: @Holger You are right it's not used...In the beginning I wanted to first have all the relevant lamps in a set and then use a separate stream, but obviously that is stupid..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact is, you use well optimized Stream API with a bit slower `if` conditions. Its syntax is correct, it works as should, but it doesn't look nice and for huge amount of data is slower.

Firstly you should move the `if` statement to `.filter` stream call:

```java
public void turnOffLampsInRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
    Set<SmartLamp> set = new HashSet<>(lamps);
    set.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getRoom() != null && rooms.contains(p.getRoom()))
            .forEach(p -> p.turnOff()); // conditions checked already
}
```

Next, the `.filter` can be split into separated ones:

```java
public void turnOffLampsInRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
    Set<SmartLamp> set = new HashSet<>(lamps);
    set.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getRoom() != null)
            .filter(p -> rooms.contains(p.getRoom())) // the same meaning
            .forEach(p -> p.turnOff());
}
```

And finally change the call to method reference:

```java
public void turnOffLampsInRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
    Set<SmartLamp> set = new HashSet<>(lamps);
    set.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getRoom() != null)
            .filter(p -> rooms.contains(p.getRoom()))
            .forEach(SmartLamp::turnOff); // method reference
}
```

The main advantage is stream optimization, but it also is far easier to read step-by-step what does the streaming do.

Comment: I understand it now..I'm so used to if statements I have a hard time with streams...

Comment: I have some problems recognizing that the `if` will be slower than using streams. The condition is the same and must be executed in both cases. And the stream must also somehow have some *branching* depending on that condition.  JMH testing for this use case results in `if` being about 10% faster.

Comment: @user16320675 Stream API is optimized, It's far more complex than simple calling predicate. As we can open and close streams, the Stream call know all operations and can optimize them to use the best performance.

Comment: Stream do not do magic. Don’t use “performance” as a reason to use `filter` instead of `if`.

Comment: @user16320675 the main reason, the Stream API does not compete with a loop for such an example, is HotSpot’s default setting of `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=9`. We override it with a setting of `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=20` in our daily work and don’t experience noticeably raised JIT compilation times, but much better Stream performance. Still, it’s not faster than a manually written `if`, of course, as it still executes the equivalent `if` under the hood.

Comment: @user16320675 I know that you weren’t talking about a loop, but the loop is the extreme end in the possible comparisons, loop vs forEach() vs stream().forEach() vs stream().filter().forEach(). These approaches differ in the amount of inlining required to get to the same performance, as they are still doing the same on a fundamental level. That’s what I tried to say, the optimizer may eliminate all abstractions under the right circumstances, but a manual `if` won’t be slower than an `if` hidden in a stream pipeline stage.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `if`, filter using the conditions:

```
set.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getRoom() != null)
.filter(p -> rooms.contains(p.getRoom()))
.forEach(SmartLamp::turnOff);
```

Note the use of the method reference `SmartLamp::turnOff`, which is generally preferred to the equivalent lambda `p -> p.turnOff()`.